# Is it possible to decompile ex5? What are some hints in how one would do so?

Tags: decompilation

I am creating an expert advisor. I am wondering how people can decompile the ex5 to mq5 for meta trader. Does anyone have any insight on this?

Comment: Please, I paid recently a robot for 3 days trial and the I paid the rest of money to get the full version but the owner doesn't want to send me the unlimited version. I want to decompile it in order to use it. It's a robot in .ex5 format. I used it in mt5. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe *.ex4 and *.ex5 are encrypted.
(Metatrader is VMProtected itself).

Anyone who did it already could pass this first layer of protection and I guess would almost have a source code or a pseudo C code